# Can we get unread messages or events one by one in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

> I want to process unread messages one by one on consumer.

Here some basic explanation.

1. Publishing messages in one topic `XYZ` and Partition `1`.
2. One consumer is listening on `XYZ` topic from Partition `1`.
3. consumer is offline and there are **10 unread messages** in topic `XYZ` and Partition `1`.

Now when Consumer comes online I want to processes each unread messages one by one.

Currently when Consumer comes online I am getting all unread messages instantly but I don't want in that way. I want one by one as per my request meaning when I request next one then and then next unread message should consume by consumer.

I tried to look around kafka and Confluent documentation but couldn't succeed.

**Is it possible and if yes then how?**

Any references are most welcome.

Comment: Why do you need this kind behavior exactly? You can poll several amount in a poll() and then process your records one by one, and commit whenever your record is process. Could you give us more details about your needs?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the numbers of messages to consume by your `Consumer` by setting the [`max.poll.records`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html) setting:

> `max.poll.records`
>
> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.

Set this value to `1` and you will get only one message when using the `poll()` method. This is also documented in the [`KafkaConsumer` class documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> 2. `max.poll.records`: Use this setting to limit the total records returned from a single call to poll. This can make it easier to predict the maximum that must be handled within each poll interval. By tuning this value, you may be able to reduce the poll interval, which will reduce the impact of group rebalancing.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you may not be committing the offsets of the record you have read in the consumer code. You could configure an auto commit in the consumer, which means every record that is read its offset is committed automatically so that it is not read again.

The Kafka consumer property to set is

props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")

Or you have the option of choosing to commit the records manually based on the result of your business logic.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("group.id", "test");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
final int minBatchSize = 200;
List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
             buffer.add(record);
         }
         if (buffer.size() >= minBatchSize) {
             insertIntoDb(buffer);
             consumer.commitSync();
             buffer.clear();
         }
     }
```

[Reference](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)